# Editing a data frame with certain conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I have a dataframe and would like to remove some specific cases depending on a simple rule: if `x` equals 2, `y` should be `NA`.

Here is an example:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
y <- c(5, 5, NA, NA, 6, 6, 4, 4)

df <- data.frame(x, y)
df

  x  y
1 1  5
2 2  5
3 1 NA
4 2 NA
5 1  6
6 2  6
7 1  4
8 2  4
```

And the output should look like that:

```
  x  y
1 1  5
2 2 NA
3 1 NA
4 2 NA
5 1  6
6 2 NA
7 1  4
8 2 NA
```

Is there a way to solve that with `ifelse`? I am grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
df$y[df$x == 2] <- NA
df

#  x  y
#1 1  5
#2 2 NA
#3 1 NA
#4 2 NA
#5 1  6
#6 2 NA
#7 1  4
#8 2 NA
```

---

Or with `replace`

```
df$y <- replace(df$y, df$x == 2, NA)
```

Using same logic in `dplyr` `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(y = replace(y, x==2, NA))
```

---

Or the `ifelse` version

```
df$y <- ifelse(df$x == 2, NA, df$y)

df %>%
   mutate(y = ifelse(x == 2, NA, y))
```

Comment: That will do it, great! But i would like to ask: could you also figure out a possibility with ifelse? I know, in my question that was not so clear, sorry for that